# Why does $\log\frac{x}{x-2}$ not equal $\log(x) - \log(x-2)$

Tags: logarithms, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples, graphing-functions

Based on log law: 
$$\log \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) = \log(a)-\log(b) \ ,$$
why does 
$$\log \left( \frac{x}{x-2} \right) \neq \log(x) - \log(x-2) \ ?$$

I have found that the graph of $\log \left( \frac{x}{x-2} \right)$ is defined for negative $x$ values while $\log(x) - \log(x-2)$ does not.
Why is this?
Sorry if this is a simple question.

Comment: Log is only defined for positive arguments.  If, say, $x=-1$ then $\frac x{x-2}=\frac 13$ is positive but $\log x$ is not.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
I've [edit]ed your post and used [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to make the formulas look better.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], and on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Did you mean to write $\frac{x}x - 2$ or $\frac{x}{x - 2}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $x=-1$.

You'll get something wrong.

For $x>2$ we have $$\ln\frac{x}{x-2}=\ln{x}-\ln(x-2)$$ and for $x<0$ we have
$$\ln\frac{x}{x-2}=\ln(-x)-\ln(2-x)$$

For $a>0$ and $b>0$ we obtain:
$$\ln\frac{a}{b}=\ln{a}-\ln{b}.$$

Answer (score 3):

For $\ln(\frac{x}{x-2})$ to defined
$$\frac{x}{x-2}\gt 0 $$
$$x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(2,\infty)$$
Only in this interval
$$\ln(\frac{x}{x-2})=\ln(\vert x\vert)-\ln(\vert x-2 \vert),\ \ x\lt 0 ,\ x\gt 2 $$

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Because your log law is valid only for positive arguments. That is $$\log(a/b)=\log a -\log b$$ is true only for positive values of $a$ and $b,$ for otherwise, $\text{RHS}$ is no longer a definite value, even if $\text{LHS}$ is. In any case one then sees that the equation is false. This happens because a quotient of two negatives is positive. So it's all a consequence of the $\text{minus}×\text{minus}=\text{plus}$ stuff.